# PowerMock prepare a class for test without using @PrepareForTest annotation

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockrunner

I have inherited a complex JUnit 4 test class which uses

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Because of a change in implementation I need to use some features from PowerMock to mock static and private methods. But when I try to switch at class level to

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
```

I get lots of errors because Mockito annotations are not being properly handled.

The question is: can I keep the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation and do programmatically the same as `@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)` just when I need it for a class?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/JUnit_Delegating_Runner) could work for your use case

Comment: `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate` is probably a step in the right direction.
Now I am into something like these annotations for the test class:

`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.springframework.*","javax.persistence.*"})
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ObjectMapper.class})
// @ContextConfiguration(classes= {MyClass.class, EntityManager.class})
//@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:META-INF/beans.xml"})`

Comment: The current problem is having the dependencies injected by Spring, which only happens if I add the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. But still can't inject interfaces like `EntityManager`.